# in Entity Framework Core Migration, Relationship data is coming null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Hello there I am using ef core. If I get the  data from database all relation model is coming null why is it ? If I use Include method  I encounter result is not changing all data is null except context model

That's my code. Does ef core migration not include data automatically ?, TContext is my Genaric dbContext

```
        public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {

                var result = context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
                return result;
            }
        }
```

I tried another code it is

```
public List<Products> GetData()
    {
        using (NervioDbContext context = new NervioDbContext())
        {
            var result = context.Products.
                Include(a => a.Category).ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Also My Product Model and Category Model**

```
  public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Related data is not included automatically. The code with `Include` should work.

Comment: @IvanStoev I used Include Method But it did not work code above

Answer (score 1):

Ef doesn't bring related data automatically

you should use `LazyLoadingProxies`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

Or when using `AddDbContext`:

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

but be aware loading all related data is not a good idea

[for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)

Comment: Thank you it is working but I guess your right I will not use it. Linq query is better